# Getting NULLs when exporting datetime column to SQL Server in Azure data flow

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am getting the latest file modified date and storing in the variable `RefDateTime`.

I need to populate this to my entire source file. So I have connected the source file and in the derived column, I have added like

```
toString(toTimestamp($LastWriteTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\''), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

My sink is SQL Server, after doing all necessary transformations, I have pushed that to my SQL Server table. I have used a the `DATETIME` datatype for this particular column in my SQL Server table.

But after the pipeline is run, I get all NULLs, instead of latest modified datetime. Am I doing anything wrong? I am attaching some screenshots here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have tried to pass the last modified date of file using `get metadata` and pass it to a dataflow. When the dataflow inserts the data, nulls are being inserted. The following is the sink data preview where I can see the data successfully.

[image]

- But the sink table shows nulls. The following is an image for reference.

[image]

- The reason for this behavior is not clear. But using `formatDateTime` function before passing the string to dataflow (with minor changes) allowed to insert the data properly.
- The following is the pipeline JSON for the demonstration.

```
{
    "name": "p1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata1",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "lastModified"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Data flow1",
                "type": "ExecuteDataFlow",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataflow": {
                        "referenceName": "dataflow1",
                        "type": "DataFlowReference",
                        "parameters": {
                            "dttt": {
                                "value": "'@{formatDateTime(activity('Get Metadata1').output.lastModified, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}'",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "compute": {
                        "coreCount": 8,
                        "computeType": "General"
                    },
                    "traceLevel": "Fine"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Script1",
                "type": "Script",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Data flow1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlDatabase1",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "scripts": [
                        {
                            "type": "Query",
                            "text": "select * from t1"
                        }
                    ],
                    "scriptBlockExecutionTimeout": "02:00:00"
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "tp": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

[image]

- The following is the dataflow JSON that I used.

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "cast1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "parameters{",
                "     dttt as string ('2023-05-18T07:11:07Z')",
                "}",
                "source(output(",
                "          id as short",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1",
                "source1 derive(dt = $dttt) ~> derivedColumn1",
                "derivedColumn1 cast(output(",
                "          dt as timestamp 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'",
                "     ),",
                "     errors: true) ~> cast1",
                "cast1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     input(",
                "          id as integer,",
                "          animal as string",
                "     ),",
                "     deletable:false,",
                "     insertable:true,",
                "     updateable:false,",
                "     upsertable:false,",
                "     format: 'table',",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     errorHandlingOption: 'stopOnFirstError') ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

- You can see that the data is being successfully inserted. The following is an output image reference for the same.

Comment: Can i know what is the datatype your giving at Sql server side while creating table . I have given DATETIME.  And i tried the above , still getting Null. Can you just try like " Get the latestModifiedDate of a file ,and put it in a variable string using set variable , and Create a parameter for dataflow and pass the variable from pipeline .  The date col which am getting is the latestModifieddate from getmetadata activity > Set variable activity > Dataflow.

Comment: It is datetime. Let me try using same procedure and check

Comment: Yeah when i direcrly used a string and pass it , ot works .But when I get it from a variable ,it thorws nulls at Sql table.

Comment: Hey @AzSuryaTeja, you are right. Following the same is giving nulls.

Comment: yEah . How can we handle it . Am tired off trying from my side.

Comment: Hey @AzSuryaTeja Working on it.

Comment: Hey @AzSuryaTeja, I have updated the entire answer. Check and let me know if it works